# how to check whether a customer id in df1 existed before that date in df2 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have two datasets allocated to pandas dataframes DF1,DF2. One with historical customer transactions (DF2) and another with other customer activities (DF1), I need to first keep only first occurances in DF2 to avoid any mistakes, then add a column ['existed_before'] to DF1 with input as True/False after comparing ID's and dates in both dataframes.
The logic I have in mind is something like the following:
if DF1['id'] == to DF2['ID'] and DF1['date'] > DF2['date'] then True, else it should be False or Nan in case the ID didn't exist in DF2 at all.

Below is a demonstration of the desired output,
*Notes: code should consider both id and full date (including hours/mins/sec). Also, an ID might repeat many times in both dataframes.

df1: 
id     date
1      19-01-2021 00:13:48
2      04-03-2021 06:23:21
3      06-05-2021 08:44:00
3      23-11-2021 23:18:18
4      15-12-2021 03:20:13

df2: 
id     date
1      19-01-2021 00:13:48
2      02-01-2021 09:27:23
3      06-05-2021 08:44:00

df1: 
id date existed_before
1      19-01-2021 00:13:48   False
2      04-03-2021 06:23:21   True
3      06-05-2021 08:44:00   False
3      23-11-2021 23:18:18   True
4      15-12-2021 03:20:13   NaN

Comment: so only one date per id? for both df1 and df2?

Comment: no there is actually repeated ID's in both df1 and df2. I want to create a df3 with only first occurance date to avoid potential mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got different ouput in [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with helper column:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], dayfirst=True)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = df1.sort_values('date')
df2 = df2.sort_values('date')

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                    df2.assign(first_time=True), 
                    on='date', 
                    by='id', 
                    allow_exact_matches=False)

df['first_time'] = (df['first_time'].fillna(False)
                                    .astype('boolean')
                                    .where(df['id'].isin(df2['id'])))
print (df)
   id                date  first_time
0   1 2021-01-19 00:13:48       False
1   2 2021-03-04 06:23:21        True
2   3 2021-05-06 08:44:00       False
3   3 2021-11-23 23:18:18        True
4   4 2021-12-15 03:20:13        <NA>
```

Comment: not really showing the answer I was looking for, the idea is I want to know if there was historical data of that customer in DF2 before the date/time in DF1, I modified the question and data sample to make it clearer hopefully.

Comment: @rfengineer - answer was edited and working like need, for you in real data not working?

Comment: thanks a lot! i checked and it's fulfilling the requirement with on a sample of my data but I'll have to randomly check on the larger dataset. Thanks again